# SQL - A summary table, how to fix the error of “The multi-part identifier "…" could not be bound.”

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am a new practioner of SQL Server / T-SQL and stuck in a problem for a while:

I have an SQL Table (containing more than 100,000 rows) to be used in combination with MS Excel. I am trying to write down a “Stored Procedure” automating  some data corrections. Part of My Data and the expected results are as follows:

```
Current Data                    
Date    Shift   WSNo    WONo    StockNo PTime   BDPlanned
04.01.2017  1   JP-MAK-053  7148    21842   2.250,00    0
04.01.2017  1   JP-MAK-053  7148    21842   26.550,00   2.961,00
04.01.2017  1   JP-MAK-053  7148    21843   0           0
04.01.2017  1   JP-MAK-053  7148    21843   0           0

Expected Result                 
Date    Shift   WSNo    WONo    StockNo PTime   BDPlanned
04.01.2017  1   JP-MAK-053  7148    21842   28.800,00   2.961,00
04.01.2017  1   JP-MAK-053  7148    21843   28.800,00   2.961,00
```

1) What expected:

First “Date+Shift+ WSNo (Key1)” is the Unique and the SQL Statement should calculate the “Total PTime” and/or the “Total BDPlanned” for the Key1.

Then the Key1-based calculated results should be evenly distributed over the items based on the second Unique “Date+Shift+WSNo+StokNo (Key2)”.

(Note: The Expected Results are to be stored in a new Table other than the Current Table)

2) In order to reach the results I tried the below mentioned Statements:

a)

```
CREATE TABLE #myTable1
        (Date date,
        Shift varchar(2),
        WSNo varchar(25),
        WONo Float,
        StockNo float,
        PTime float);


INSERT INTO #myTable1
SELECT Date, Shift, WSNo, WONo, SUM(PTime) AS TPTime
    FROM myTable
    WHERE WONo = 3786
    GROUP BY Date, Shift, WSNo, WONo, CONCAT(Date,'+' , Shift,'+' ,WONo)



CREATE TABLE #myTable2
        (Date date,
        Shift varchar(2),
        WSNo varchar(25),
        WONo Float,
        StockNo float,
        PTime float);

INSERT INTO #myTable2
SELECT Date, Shift, WSNo, WONo, StockNo, SUM(PTime) AS TPTime
    FROM myTable
    WHERE WONo = 3786
    GROUP BY Date, Shift, WSNo, WONo, StockNo,


SELECT  StockNo
    ,[TPTime] = CASE T21.PTime
        WHEN (
                SELECT S22.PTime
                FROM  #myTable2 T22
                WHERE T22.StockNo = T21.StockNo
                )
            THEN (
                    SELECT SUM(PTime)
                    FROM #myTable1 S11
                    WHERE T21.StockNo = T11.StockNo
                    )


FROM #myTable2 T21
```

The Error Mesage:
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

b) When I set another  Statement using “INNER JOIN” I got the below mentioned Error:

“Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The multi-part identifier "T11.PTime" could not be bound.”

c) For another Try, by setting the “StockNo” as variable (@StockNo) and thus assigning calculated values to the variable from each Temp Table; I again got the error mesage of

“The multi-part identifier "…" could not be bound.”

I am not sure If the same problem has been answered in this platform before, but It would be very much appreciated should you help me sorting this out.

Thank you very much in advance and very very sorry for my long mail.

Best regards

Comment: `StockNo float`?! Maybe it doesn't mean what I think it means, but a _stock number_, e.g. a SKU, would never be a `float`. If a table has multiple rows for a given `StockNo` then a subquery that filters _only_ on `StockNo` will return data from multiple rows. Your subqueries should be returning single values, so you need to find another filter to reduce the number of results. (Aggregation, e.g. `Sum`, will do that.)

Comment: Dear HABO, Thank you very much for your comments and swift answer. I already changed StokNo as "int". About the Aggregation with SUM: I thought that I had applied it in the SELECT statement. Am I missing s'thing.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(PTime) FROM #myTable1 S11 WHERE T21.StockNo = 11.StockNo` will return a single value due to the aggregation provided by `Sum`. `SELECT S22.PTime FROM  #myTable2 T22 WHERE T22.StockNo = T21.StockNo` may return more than one value, but you have it in a `when` clause that expects a single value.

Comment: Dear HABO, thanks for your comments. I will keep them in my mind. Thanks again. Best regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want window function :

```
select Date, Shift, WSNo, WONo, StockNo, sum(PTime) over(), sum(BDPlanned) over()
from #myTable1 mt;
```

Comment: Dear Yogesh, Thank you very much for your answer and quick reply. I will try your statement and let you know about the result. Best regrads...

Comment: Dear Yogesh, I tried your sugestion and It worked very well. My Statement is: `select Date, Shift, WSNo, WONo, StockNo, sum(PTime) over(CONCAT(Date,'+' , Shift,'+' ,WONo)) from #myTable1 mt;`  **Thank you very much** You saved my life:)